# Adding formula in Created column which you do not know the column value

Tags: vba, excel

I have performed a find function in Excel that looks for a specific value and inserts a new column 2 places to the right, As this value can be anywhere, I am not sure of the column value(A,B,C,D,etc.) How do I add a formula to this newly created column if I am unsure of the value?

This is what I have so far:

```
 With Range("A1:Z1")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="US", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        lastColumn = rFind.Column
    Columns(lastColumn + 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range((lastColumn + 2) & LR).Formula = "=(5)"
    End If
```

Comment: Your new column is `lastColumn + 2`

Comment: when I do that in Range((lastColumn + 2) & LR).Formula = "=(5)" I get an error mismatch

Comment: how would i create that for Range? I am trying to fill down to the last row of the new column..

Comment: Let's say "US" is found in Range("***D4***"). You `Insert` a column in position F, pushing all beyond that one column to the right. What formula are you hoping to put into column F in this example?

Comment: "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],'[ABC.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1,1,FALSE)"

Comment: To avoid error mistmatch you should use `Cells(1, (lastColumn + 2)).Formula = "=(5)"` however I am quite sure that is not your ultimate goal :)

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer using that formula (with a tweak to the R1C1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

```
Sub test()

With Range("A1:Z1")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="US", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        lastColumn = rFind.Column
    Columns(lastColumn + 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range(Cells(1, (lastColumn + 2)), Cells(123, (lastColumn + 2))).Formula = "=(5)"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Replace 123 with last row number.

Per request for multiple conditions finding (requieres that "US" and "New Price" are in the same column):

```
Sub test()

    lastColumn = Evaluate(" Match(""US"" & ""New Price"", A1:Z1 & A2:Z2, 0)")
    Columns(lastColumn + 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range(Cells(1, (lastColumn + 2)), Cells(123, (lastColumn + 2))).Formula = "=(5)"

End Sub
```

In case of described issue:

```
Sub test2()

Dim rng As Range

With Range("A1:Z1")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="US", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        lastColumn = rFind.Column
    End If
End With

Set rng = Range(Cells(2, lastColumn), Cells(2, lastColumn + 7))

final_Column = Application.Match("New Price", rng, 0)

lastColumn = lastColumn + final_Column

Columns(lastColumn + 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range(Cells(1, (lastColumn + 2)), Cells(123, (lastColumn + 2))).Formula = "=(5)"


End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to ask one additional question for assistance? I am currently just looking for 1 field - "US" In RowA1:Z1 -- How would I go about looking for two specific fields? EX) "US" in Row A1:Z1 AND "New Price" In Row A2:Z2?

Comment: Please note that this is quite rough and volatile solution. Hardcoded ranges are almost always not a good idea. However, knowing how to approach the problem you may be able to upgrade the code by yourself.

Comment: Type mismatch sometimes means that Match have not returned any value. This means that you do not have proper data in your sheet. Above solution works only if you have "US" and "New Price" in the same column. In my test worksheet I have "US" in cell D1 and "New Price" in cell D2 and it works flawlessly.

Comment: ohh, no the issue is the headers in Row A1:Z1 are merged to be 7 cells each. And the headers in Row A2:Z2 might not be directly under the first merged cell. So excel would likely show that 'New Price' will be 3 rows to the right of "US"

Comment: Edited. Don't forget to mark/upviote answers if you find them helpfull :)

Comment: For example `row_no = 2` then `Range(Cells(row_no, (lastColumn + 2)), Cells(row_no, (lastColumn + 2))).Select`

Answer (score 0):

The following will put that formula (in the example it would go in column F), referring back to column D for the lookup key:

```
rFind.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[ABC.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1,1,FALSE)"
```

PS. `C1` is not much of a table to perform a `VLOOKUP` on but okay..

Comment: I tried using this solution however, it leaves the cells blank. Even if I just add (5) to test they stay blank

Comment: Looks (from the accepted answer) that I've misinterpreted your request. Glad you've got it working.